# Webassembly: possible to have shared structs?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, rust, webassembly

I am wondering if, using C (or C++ or Rust) and javascript, I am able to do CRUD operations to a shared data structure. Using the most basic example, here would be an example or each of the operations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct Person {
    int age;
    char* name;
} Person;

int main(void) {

    // init
    Person* sharedPersons[100];
    int idx=0;

    // create
    sharedPersons[idx] = (Person*) {12, "Tom"};

    // read
    printf("{name: %s, age: %d}", sharedPersons[idx]->name, sharedPersons[idx]->age);

    // update
    sharedPersons[idx]->age = 11;

    // delete
    sharedPersons[idx] = NULL;

}
```

Then, I would like to be able to do the exact same thing in Javascript, and both be able to write to the same shared `sharedPersons` object. How could this be done? Or does the setup need to be something like a 'master-slave' where one just needs to pass back information to the other and the master does all the relevant actions? I'm hoping that there's a way do CRUD on a shared data object in webassembly, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

As a reference: https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/contributing/design/js-objects-in-rust.html

Comment: I can only speak for Rust+wasmbindgen flow, but since webassembly uses different memory spaces, any objects created stay on their respective memories. Across that boundary, only primitives (integers, strings) are copied over, and anything else just uses proxies.

Comment: @kmdreko I see: so there's no way for the rust side to write to the js side and vice-versa, and there's no such thing as a shared memory space? What do you mean by "proxies" ?

Comment: what's the usecase for this? if you export your CRUD functions you can call them from javascript; why would you ever need the javascript to personally mess with the memory? (I'm sure there *is* a usecase, I'm just finding it difficult to think of one.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Creating the object

Let's create the object in C and return it:

```
typedef struct Person {
    int age;
    char* name;
} Person;

Person *get_persons(void) {
    Person* sharedPersons[100];
    return sharedPersons;
}
```

You could also create the object in JS, but it's harder. I'll come back to this later.

In order for JS to get the object, we've defined a function (`get_persons`) that returns (a pointer to) it. In this case it's an array, but of course it could have been a single object. The thing is, there must be a function that will be called from JS and that provides the object.

## Compiling the program

```
emcc \
    -s "SINGLE_FILE=1" \
    -s "MODULARIZE=1" \
    -s "ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1" \
    -s "EXPORT_NAME=createModule" \
    -s "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_get_persons', '_malloc', '_free']" \
    -s "EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['cwrap', 'setValue', 'getValue', 'AsciiToString', 'writeStringToMemory']" \
    -o myclib.js
    person.c
```

I don't remember why we have a leading underscore in `_get_persons`, but that's how Emscripten works.

## Getting the object in JS

```
const createModule = require('./myclib');

let myclib;
let Module;

export const myclibRuntime = createModule().then((module) => {
  get_persons: Module.cwrap('get_persons', 'number', []),
});
```

What this does is create a `get_persons()` JS function that is a wrapper of the C `get_persons()` function. The return value of the JS function is "number". Emscripten knows that the C `get_persons()` function returns a pointer, and the wrapper will convert that pointer to a JS number. (Pointers in WASM are 32-bit.)

## Manipulating the object in JS

```
const persons = get_persons();
Module.getValue(persons, 'i32');  // Returns the age of the first person
Module.AsciiToString(Module.getValue(persons + 4, 'i32'));  // Name of first person

// Set the second person to be "Alice", age 18
const second_person = persons + 8;
Module.setValue(second_person, 18, 'i32');
const buffer = Module._malloc(6);  // Length of "Alice" plus the null terminator
Module.writeStringToMemory("Alice", buffer);
Module.setValue(second_person + 4, buffer, 'i32');
```

This is a fairly low level way of doing it, although [there seems to be an even lower level way](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html?highlight=setvalue#access-memory-from-javascript). As other people have suggested, there may be higher level tools to help in C++ and Rust.

## Creating the object in JS

You can create objects in JS by using `_malloc()` (and free them with `_free()`) as we did with the string above, and then pass their pointers to C functions. But, as I said, creating them in C is probably easier. In any case, anything `_malloc()`ed must eventually be freed (so the string creation above is incomplete). The [FinalizationRegistry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry) can help with this.

Comment: Not a C dev, but want to clarify my understanding of this approach.  The object is never really accessed or present in JavaScript? I.e. you get an int representing the pointer, and if you want to access properties of the object, you pass the int to the WASM module which does the object access then returns the primitive value.  I.e. because you can't pass non-primitive types then you instead pass int pointers and the object never really exists on the JavaScript side?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

WebAssembly stores objects within [linear memory](https://radu-matei.com/blog/practical-guide-to-wasm-memory/), a contiguous array of bytes that the module can read and write to. The host environment (typically JavaScript within the web browser) can also read and write to linear memory, allowing it to access the objects that the WebAssembly modules stores there.

There are two challenges here:

1. How do you find where your WebAssembly module has stored an object?
2. How is the object encoded?

You need to ensure that you can read and write these objects from both the WebAssembly module and the JavaScript host.

I'd pick a known memory location, and a known serialisation format and use that to read/write from both sides.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there a suggested serialization format for this? I've heard about using Arrow...would that be the best option here. In other words, let's say we have a 1GB+ shared data object, what would be the fastest way to read from the data on both ends?

Comment: If you use Embind in Emscripten, or wasm-bindgen in Rust, they allow doing this for you automatically - that is, they'll wrap any C++/Rust objects you annotate and expose them to JS as regular objects, allowing you to modify them from either side.

Comment: @colinE -- thanks for your answer, I've added a bounty, want to add in some more details here?

Comment: @RReverser cool, want to show a very basic example implementation, either C++ or rust is fine (though would prefer C++ if have the choice).

Comment: Did you check out the docs? There are plenty examples.